# microsoft graph installing app for other user returns "code": "Conflict"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

For `microsoft teams` I want to programatically install an app for another user.

I am following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging

The authenticated user is an admin for the organization and I am using their `token` in the `authorization header`.

I am using `graph explorer` to call the following:

```
POST /users/{user-id}/teamwork/installedApps
{
   "teamsApp@odata.bind" : "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/appCatalogs/teamsApps/{teamsAppid}"
}
```

And it is returning `"code": "Conflict"`

It worked when I use the same `user-id` as the authenticated user but it shows the `conflict` issue when the `user-id` is for a different user (within the same organization).

The authorized user has accepted all necessary permissions.

The other user does not currently have the app installed.

I'm using `graph explorer` and I selected all permissions for `TeamsAppInstallation` and `TeamsApp`
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using application permission or delegated permissions, Could you please confrom?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT not sure I added permissions above that I consented to in graph explorer.

Comment: Could you please share screen shots of the request and error?

Answer (score 2):

I was using a user id that already installed the app. The conflict meant that they already had the app installed. Once I installed the app for the user then this worked successfully.